# Cannot find "AuthorityKeyIdentifier" value in x509Certificates object PowerShell

Tags: powershell, x509, authoritykeyidentifier

I have no problem extracting the "SubjectKeyIdentifier" value from the x509certificates object, which I do by first setting the X509 object to variable $Cert and then executing the following line:

```
$Cert.Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier
```

That value corresponds to what I see in the MMC GUI.

However, there is no such value or option for

```
$Cert.Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.
```

I can go further into the object via:

```
$Cert.Extensions.Oid
```

And that produces two columns such as:

```
Value       FriendlyName
2.5.29.14   Subject Key Identifier
2.4.29.35   Authority Key Identifier
```

However, there is no way that I have found to get the actual or true value of the Authority Key Identifier like I did for the Subject Key Identifier and which corresponds to the value in the MMC GUI.
TO confirm, this is a leaf level certificate and the GUI does show a long stringed value for the Subject Key Identifier.

How can I extract that value in the object?

Comment: `$Cert.Extensions` should contain a list of `X509Extension` objects. Could you search through those for one that is for the `AuthorityKeyIdentifier` property?

Answer (score 0):

The framework doesn't have a built-in decoder for Authority Key Identifier.  You'd have to use an ASN.1 DER reader, such as https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-corefxlab/package/nuget/System.Security.Cryptography.Asn1.Experimental, Bouncy Castle, or other non-built-in pieces of technology (or hand-roll it) and decode the X509Extension.RawData value according to the encoding in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1.

Comment: Hey, thank you both for your quick and knowledgeable answers.  After reading them, I'm wondering about the "hand-roll it" comment made by bartonjs.  Apparently, the Framework version 4.8 has a class named AsnEncodedData Class.  Would I theoretically be able to use this class to decoode the AKI or am I misunderstanding that page?

Comment: @F.S. Sorry, you’ve misinterpreted it. It just represents that the data is something that is ASN encoded data, but X509Extension already derived that type. Actual ASN data readers aren’t public API :(.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up.  I just saw your Git Hub post from July 2017 requesting that the API should be made public.  A year long conversation from that post .  Looks like you yourself were working on it.  So, how did it end?

Comment: I hadn't finished that post yet.  I mean to ask, is the API for the .Net and Core .Net Framework still in private development?  Is there any ETA for it going public or ?/  What's the status?

Answer (score 0):

As bartonjs said, there is no built-in support for AKI extension in PowerShell or .NET. You have to use 3rd party libraries or tools. Though, if you are allowed to use PS modules, you can give a try to my [PowerShell PKI (PSPKI)](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSPKI) module. The module ships a library that contains classes for most X.509 extensions, including AKI.

After importing the module, you can call:

```
$cert.ResolvedExtensions
```

which returns an a collection of decoded extensions:

```
PS C:\> $cert.ResolvedExtensions | ?{$_.oid.value -eq "2.5.29.35"}

IncludedComponents : KeyIdentifier
KeyIdentifier      : 0159abe7dd3a0b59a66463d6cf200757d591e76a
IssuerNames        :
SerialNumber       :
Critical           : False
Oid                : 2.5.29.35 (Authority Key Identifier)
RawData            : {48, 22, 128, 20...}


PS C:\>
```